# Asp.net core, what is difference between cache Taghelper and IMemoryCache?

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I am workinog on `Asp.net core 2.1` project. In my project, there is a menu that bind from 2 tables `Group` and `subGroup`.

`Group` Table contains `Id` and `GroupName` and `subGroup` table contains `Id`,`groupId` and `subGroupName`.

Now to improve the speed of loading the site i want use caching.

1 - What is the best way to `cache` data from database.

2 - What is the diffrence between `<cache></cache>` (Which is used in the `view`) and `IMemoryCache` (Which is used in the `controller` or `class`) in asp.net core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IMemoryCache` if you want to cache just the query results server side or you can use `Cache TagHelper` to cache a specific part of the view which may or may not contain the results of that said query.

Also with `IMemoryCache` you can have global settings where with `Cache TagHelper` you'll have to do it manually for each tag use.

Fun fact: at its core `Cache TagHelper` implementation uses an instance of an `IMemoryCache`.

Comment: which one is better for use in `menu` ?

Comment: If the menu is static or doesn't change often, you'll probably have better results with `Cache TagHelper`, else go for `IMemoryCache`